How can I fix these auto-correction issues with Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2022?
I am experiencing behavior I haven't seen before in Visual Studio 2022 when working on a legacy Classic ASP project.
Case 1:
I have the code:
.Parameters.append .CreateParameter("@FieldID", 3,1,, CInt(fieldID))

Notice the space, which is the correct syntax.
If I click on the line then click off of it, it removes the space:
.Parameters.append.CreateParameter("@FieldID", 3,1,, CInt(fieldID))

This is incorrect. Not to mention, if I don't pay attention to where I click, I get all sorts of weird errors.
Case 2:
When I type Option Explicit it automatically adds the word On when I click off the line:
Option Explicit

becomes
Option Explicit On

I have unchecked any code completion options, etc. in the Tools > Options > Text Editor section of Visual Studio, to no avail.

I wouldn't recommend trying to edit Classic ASP using Visual Studio especially later editions as support dwindles with each passing version. Instead, look into using Visual Studio Code which is open-source and has many extensions including Classic ASP syntax and highlighting ones.

My entire team uses Visual Studio 2022 Professional, none of them are experiencing this problem. I can't switch IDEs.

I tried to create an empty ASP.NET Web project, then added an HTML file and added ASP code similar to yours, but the problem you encountered did not occur. The settings I used were all default. I suggest you check with your team members to see if the settings are consistent.
